# Python 3.7.6 visible in vscode terminal but not ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed vscode recently and have been using Python 3.7 under vscode's terminal. Before installing vscode, I used Ubuntu's terminal to run 3.7 without problem. But accidentally I realized that I can't run 3.7 under normal Ubuntu terminal. I can only get 2.7 (I think this is the default version in Ubuntu). I can't even see conda's environment. So to use 3.7, I have to use vscode's terminal.

Do I need to set something up somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Update the PATH environment variable in your .bashrc so it includes the directory where Python 3.7 is installed.

Comment: cool, thanks. just saw your reply. that works!